# Vim indent JavaScript files with spaces instead of tab

Tags: javascript, vim

I have the following vimrc configuration which is working fine for Python files:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set tabstop=4
```

So when I press tab it's an alias to 4 spaces.

But it doesnt seem to work with JavaScript files.

When I press tab it always add a tab plus 2 spaces for every indentation.
I am ok with the two spaces but how can I replace that tab with 4 spaces?

All the code is indented with spaces I dont want start adding tabs/spaces mix

I know you can specify the tabs/spaces for specific files but I cant make it work

```
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal shiftwidth=1 tabstop=4
```

Comment: Just a tangent comment: if you want to fix your existing files, the tools `expand` and `unexpand` might come in handy. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To configure 4-space indentation, you need to `:setlocal tabstop=4 expandtab`. To be safe, it's recommended to also reset the `'softtabstop'` option to `0`. Usually, you want the `'shiftwidth'` option aligned to the chosen indent; that would be `shiftwidth=4`:

```
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 softtabstop=0 expandtab
```

I would recommend putting the options into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim` instead of defining lots of `:autocmd FileType javascript`; it's cleaner and scales better; requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`, though.

If that doesn't work, some *filetype plugin* (or another `:autocmd`) may override your settings. You can check with

```
:verbose setlocal shiftwidth? tabstop? softtabstop? expandtab?
```

Comment: mmm It doesnt work, and the :verbose says it has been defined in vimrc (where I put the autocmd to test it)  However it seems to work if I add to the vimrc just set shiftwidth=4 and set expandtab after the configuration written on my question, maybe vim is not detecting the javascript file? or any vim pathogen stuff is overriding it?

Comment: Could be; you can check via `:setlocal filetype?`, which should return `javascript`.

Comment: yep, it says javascript, it's strange I cannot make it work with autocmd but it works if I just add the options separately at vimrc

Comment: Try switching from `:autocmd` to the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim`; that gives you at least the precise location with `:verbose`, and maybe solves a problem with autocmd ordering.